# R: Convert rows with multiple columns to rows with just two colums (row ID and data point)

Tags: r

I am very new to R, and trying to reconfigure a large dataframe (several million records) to permit analysis.

The dataframe looks like:

```
ID   Dx1   Dx2   Dx3 .....Dx33
1    12    11    0 
2    3     1     2
3    44    9     6
```

I need to convert it to look like

```
ID   Dx
1    12
1    11
1    0
2    3
2    4
```

etc..

Assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

In case anyone is interested:
The dataframe has a subject ID number and 1 to 33 associated ICD10 codes (diagnosis codes).   I plan to use the Comorbidity package (https://github.com/ellessenne/comorbidity) to calculate Elixhauser scores for each subject.  Comorbidity requires the data to be in this format.

Comment: Try `library(tidyr); gather(df1, key, Dx, - ID) %>% select(-key)`

Comment: Some optimization and tidiness can be achieved by knowing that wide and long diagnostic data have particular characteristics. The CRAN package [icd](https://cran.r-project.org/package=icd) of which I'm the author, offers `icd::wide_to_long` and `icd::long_to_wide`. They actually use base R internally, but do the job quickly, accounting for the typical structure of diagnostic data.